# Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Tags: c#, linq

The code below was working fine until something happened and now it's returning this error msg: 
    **Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'**

Here is my code what worked before but now something is causing to throw this error.

```
var Amount = (from x in db.Users where x.userID == ID select (x.fee)).Sum() ?? 0;
```

'fee' defined as

```
public int? fee { get; set; } //and tried this too

public Nullable<int> fee { get; set; }
```

From what I understand The "??" operator cannot be called on a type that is not nullable.

Making non-nullable or removing the '?' from 'int?' doesn't do anything.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Ceci

Comment: C#, the operator ?? is called  null coalescing operator to check if a given value is null and if it is null then the value following ??  will be assigned to the value.

Comment: If you use `var Amount = (from x in db.Users where x.userID == ID select (x.fee)).Sum()` what is the `Type` of `Amount`?

Comment: Nullable<int> and int? are strictly equivalent, this shouldn't be issue. I cannot reproduce your compilation error. Can you create a [mcve] ? come code that compiles and enough to reproduce the problem, and as short as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't need to use `?? 0` at all.
This will lead to :

```
var Amount = (from x in db.Users where x.userID == ID select (x.fee)).Sum();
```

Example :

http://rextester.com/UVLX36130

The LINQ `Sum` function already accept nullable types. It ignores null values (or consider them as their default value 0 here, which is equivalent).

Also, it will return the same nullable type as what you are summing, `int?` in this case.

---

I don't really understand how you get your error with the provided code, as these will not cause any errors :

```
int?[] test = {1,2,3, null};

var sum = (from x in test select x).Sum(); // no error here

Console.WriteLine(sum);

var sum2 = (from x in test select x).Sum() ?? 0; // neither there is an error here

Console.WriteLine(sum2);
```

However, this doesn't compile :

```
int sum3 = (from x in test select x).Sum(); // compilation error
```

with this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Which is **not** the same error as you have.

Could you please give some more information on the version of C# you are using ?

Can you double-check that the compilation error is indeed on this line ?

Or better, give a compilable example that exhibit the problem ?

---

Docs on Sum() : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Removing the "?? 0' worked. Thank you!